# Colored syntax and terminal when using SSH from terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, syntax, syntax-highlighting

Ok. So I use pico as a text editor. In ubuntu and when I ssh using putty I have colored syntax and colored terminals. When I ssh through ubuntu terminal I have solid white text. I always ssh into my school's servers to use their storage. How can I fix this so that I have a colored terminal through ubuntu. I've looked up a few different things involving $TERM and nothing is working. I also see people saying you have to fix the .profle or ./bash file. Can someone please help me. I'm trying to learn and use ubuntu from now on and not having colored syntax is horrible. Thanks in advance

Comment: If anyone else is having this problem it's that my TERM was changing upon ssh using terminal. To resolve I put "export TERM xterm" is my .bashrc file and now I always have colored syntax.